# C-for loop weird

Tags: c, for-loop

what does

```
for(;i;)
```

and

```
for(;;)
```

mean in c programming?

```
for(;i;)
printf("hjj");
```

what happens in the above program?

```
int i=1;
for(;;)
```

Will the compiler enter into the loop at all?

Answer (score 4):

`for(;;)` is an infinite loop. `for(;i;)` will terminate when value of `i` becomes `0`.

In your case,

```
int i=1;
for(;;)
```

for will be an infinite loop until inner block breaks out of loop.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break-down the `for` statement (see the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) 6.8.5.3):

```
for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
```

in

```
for(;;)
```

you are omitting the initialisation statement (*clause-1*) and the loop-body expressions (*expression-3*), and I assume you are clear that these mean just no operation.

The controlling part is the middle one, **expression-2**.  This expression is evaluated to true or false at the start of each iteration.  If it evaluates to true then the next iteration is executed. Now I go back to [the standard](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.8.5.3.html):

"*An omitted expression-2 is replaced by a nonzero constant.*"

As you probably know, a "*nonzero constant*" evaluates to true in a boolean context.    Therefore:

```
for (;;)
```

is *equivalent* to:

```
while (1)
```

so the loop will continue to iterate, an infinite loop, unless `break` is executed or an external interrupt (like `<CTRL>C`) intervenes.

So, taking that a step further:

```
for(;i;)
```

depends on the value of `i`.  If `i` is non-zero then you have an infinite loop again, but if `i` is zero (false) then the loop will not iterate at all.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, cleared my concept :)